# Running a python file via java

Tags: java

ok I am trying to execute a python file (test1.py) with a java program.

Here's our code:

```py
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class pro {
    public Process mProcess;

    public pro() {
        Process process;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("test1.py");
            mProcess = process;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Raised" + e.toString());
        }
        InputStream stdout = (mProcess != null) ? mProcess.getInputStream(): null;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("stdout: " + line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in reading output" + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

the line `process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "test1.py"});` throws `Exception Raisedjava.io.IOException: Cannot run program "test1.py": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I see is in this line

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("test1.py");
```

test1.py is just a python file, you need to tell exec how to run this file like we do in shell or command prompt

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test1.py");
```

Comment: basicly yes. slightly more complicated, as the python folder is a folder deep, but yes.

Comment: i have come to the conclusion that `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("test1.py");` executes a command on the command line, and I think everything else was extraneous. I think.